# What is the best approach for a Java developer to learn C++

Tags: java, c++

I consider myself an experienced Java developer and am planning to get started with learning C++.

If you had same experience, i.e learn C++ after Java, I would like to hear your thoughts on what is the best approach at doing this.

[Update] "the best approach" was not well quantified. What I am looking for is to leverage my existing java knowledge and programming experience so that I can quickly ramp up on C++.

Comment: My biggest beef with Java programmers who join our C++ team: Stop newing everything!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've taught C++ to Java people, even though I learned them the other direction.

Are you comfortable with C?  If not, read [Kernighan and Ritchie](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).  *Many many* peculiarities of C++ are explained by the desire for C++ to be a "Better C" with C's basic expression syntax.

You should get [Stroustrup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201889544).

I think well of [Thinking in C++](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) by Bruce Eckels.

I've used [The C++ FAQ Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309831), by Cline, Lomow, and Girou; I refer to it pretty often.  Marshall Cline has [C++ FAQ content on his site](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/index.html), too.

#### Update

You might also look at [C++ for Java Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013919424X).  I don't know the book but it looks decent.

Comment: Try Effective c++ series with Stroustrup concurrently

Comment: A newer version of the Stroustrup book: [publisher](http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-programming-language-9780321563842), [amazon](http://amzn.com/0321563840)

Comment: Is that link for Kernighan and Ritchie still the most up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, that’s the most recent version. For a really good time dig up the first edition, one of the best examples of technical writing ever.

Answer (score 13):

My proposal would be to write highly **pointer-based thing**, like a linked list library, BST library, etc. The code should be STL-free, similar to pure C. You should build application using such library (eg. sort algorithms?) and learn how to deal with all the pitfalls which will for sure come up, if it's your first C/C++ code.

In my opinion the most important fundamental in knowing C++ is to understand pointers and low level memory representation of classes and structures. It's like an enlightenment after which everything is simple and clear ;)

Comment: Yes, implementing data structures from scratch is a good way to learn about pointers, explicit memory (de)allocation etc.

Comment: STL is now an integral part of C++ and an experienced C++ engineer will expect c++ code to use the standard paradigms.

Answer (score 5):

I would start with Effective C++ and More Effective C++ by Scott Meyers.  These two books go over some really good best-practices for C++.

http://www.aristeia.com/books.html

Answer (score 2):

Others have already specified the required books. I would like to add just couple of points to be noted: ( as background is java)

- C++ doesnot provide you the Garbage
  collection ( as in Java). Hence, you
  must be very perticular about memory leaks. Always use `delete` the memory allocated on heap using `new`.
  Try to remember the [Free-Store
  management](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html) in FAQ while writing
  the C++ applications.
- Most often in C++ you may have to
  work with pointers ( missing in
  Java). Learn pointers ( books
  suggested by @Charlie Martin)
  effectively and use them.
- One you are familiar with C++, learn
  the basics of STL and use
  effectively. ( Book By [Josuttis](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/)
  and [Scott Meyers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629))

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly disagree with learning C first, and with trying tgo learn C++ from the Effective books, excellent though they are. Instead, get hold of a copy of [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/) by Andrew Koenig and Barabra Moo - this is written by two of the original C++ development group and will teach you how to use modern C++ features.

Comment: For a dissenting view see http://www.idinews.com/KoenigRvw.html

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how saying a book is excellent and that he enthusiastically recommends it dissents from my recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

"C++ for Java Programmers" by Mark Allen Weiss is a good intro book for seasoned Java programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Andy and Charlie already gave you the books, so I will indicate the [boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries and the [Qt](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/) framework.

Boost gives you some basic functions to work with so you don't need to create everything from scratch.

Qt, as you may know, is a GUI framework, and I find it very enjoyable to use. There is a book called "C++ GUI Programming With Qt 4" that covers all the important topics to learn Qt.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to sound a little funny, but you asked for the *best* way, not the quickest.  I'd suggest you start by **learning C first**, before you learn C++.  [Kernighan and Ritchie](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/) is one of the best language books ever written.  When you know C and Java, you'll be able to write good, clear programs in a sensible subset of C++ with almost no additional effort.

Comment: What would be the "quickest" way then?

Comment: Learning C first isn't really a good idea, as a developer would then have to unlearn certain things to learn C++ (e.g. I/O)

Answer (score 1):

[K&R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) and [Stroustrup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840) are classics, and eventually you should get them, but I don't think they are good introduction for C++ beginners. Thinking in modern C++ is thinking in classes, templates, exceptions, and streams, none of which available in C language.

I would recommend a college-level textbook on C++ like [Deitel and Deitel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136152503).
[image]

After playing around, you should focus on learning to write a class that behaves like a built-in class. That means providing a copy constructor, `operator=`, `operator==`, `operator<<`, etc.. Along the way you'll meet various concepts embedded in the language of C++. I would agree with others on [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889) is a must read once you are comfortable with the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Learn [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). Trust me on this; I'm both a Java and C++ developer; I can tell you Qt makes C++ language closer to Java. Don't just learn the bare-bone C++.

C++ with Qt makes you infinitely more productive. I used to combine so many different libraries (Boost, Intel's, database connectors, etc..) just to achieve the kind of stuff we do (high-performance/real-time computing). At the end, I found that more than 80% of what I need is already included in Qt.

Not to mention, imo, Qt has the best documentation on any framework/library I've worked on, which makes it *very* easy to just learn everything on your own.

Try it, and see for yourself.

Disclaimer: I'm just a developer--I dont work for Nokia. =p