# How to Learn C++ When you are stuck in your ways with newer Languages?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the best approach for a Java developer to learn C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789659/what-is-the-best-approach-for-a-java-developer-to-learn-c)

How would you go about learning C++ if you were "Stuck in your ways" with newer languages like Java or C#?

I've been working as a developer for 3 years, I've got both a Bachellors and a masters in computing science from a Reputable UK University...

I've written millions of lines of C# thousands of lines of Java and a few hundred lines of C...

But I don't know C++, I feel a little like I've cheated the profession by not knowing a what I think is a key language. I've written Code in C++ files, mainly for bug fixes, but it was really just C in disguise.

What is the best way to go about learning C++, if you are more used to the nice abstractions that higher level languages give you to get away from the nitty grittyness of C++.

Has anyone on SO gone from being an experienced Java, C# (or some other language) developor to a C++ programmer? if so how did you do it, was it difficult and do you have any pointers?

Comment: I used to feel just like you. I learned Java first. Now I know C++ quite well. But I'm not really sure how I did it, so I probably won't be much help...

Comment: I'd like to think "do you have any pointers" was a really clever pun.

Comment: Dupe ov http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789659/what-is-the-best-approach-for-a-java-developer-to-learn-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reading Stroustroup's C++ Programming Language.
Switched from Common Lisp.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea: try looking up all those "Java for C++ Programmers" articles, because there are so many of them.  They're written for those who took the historical path (like I did), but it seems like there ought to be an awful lot of useful information, examples, etc., of what the parallels are and how they're different.

That, and spend a lot of time developing in C++ :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much like you do any other language.  Pick a project to work on and write it in C++.  Immerse yourself in the language by reading C++ code to pick up on proper idioms.  Reading good books like Effective C++, etc... will help you write correct C++.  C++ is a really nice language that gets beat up a lot by the C# and Java programmers, so try and go into it with a positive mindset.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have some C programming skills, I would suggest [Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298) by Peter van der Linden.  It has a great section on C++ to get you from C to C++.  That should get you running with C++ syntax.  Of course you can go straight to the Stroustrup if you feel more hungry...

Get a good C/C++ compiler and get working...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start by concentrating on the commonalities among those language that you already know somewhat, i.e. namely the C syntax, classes and encapsulation from Java/C#, and from there on it's mostly a matter of the different types in C, and well ***pointers*** of course, as well as manual memory management.

A pretty good multimedia introduction (flash video with animations) to the C-family of programming languages is provided by Bruce Eckel's [Thinking in C](http://mindview.net/CDs/ThinkingInC/beta3).

Once you got these basics sorted, I would recommend to concentrate on getting to grips with the STL and eventually boost.

Also, one thing that might be worth a try in order to get started actually **using** your new knowledge, might be to start splitting your future projects into distinct modules, where certain components/parts could possibly be implemented in C++.

This encourages modular design and will provide for a way to actually learn new things and apply your knowledge step by step. This could be done for example by planning to implement one tiny part of a new project as a DLL or in managed C++ code.

And in cases where you find that you cannot directly use/embed C++ components, you could still try to follow a C++ oriented approach, deliberately sacrificing some of those Java/C# facilities that you know are not available in C++.

In other words, there's usually a common denominator between platforms and languages, in network programming it's for example BSD style sockets, on Windows there's often the possibility to make use of the Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789659/what-is-the-best-approach-for-a-java-developer-to-learn-c).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Or, vote to close it as an exact duplicate, which is what actually happened.

Comment: Very true. I was in the process of going through the "low-quality posts" review queue and came across your answer. I didn't realise the question it related to had been closed as a duplicate, or I might have just skipped it.