# C++ Implementation of String Matching Algorithm

Tags: c++, string, compare

I am implementing a string matching algorithm for a username database. My method takes an existing Username database and a new username that the person wants and it checks to see if the username is taken. if it is taken the method is supposed to return the username with a number that isn't taken in the database.

Example:

`"Justin","Justin1", "Justin2", "Justin3"`

Enter `"Justin"`

Returns `"Justin4"` since Justin and Justin with the numbers 1 through 3 are already taken.

I have already written this code in Java, and now I am writing it in C++ for practice. I have a few problems though:

1. How do you compare two strings? I have tried `strcmp` and a few others but I always get the error message: cannot convert `std::string` to `const char*` for argument 2.
2. How do you concatenate an `int` and a `string`? In Java it was as simple as using the + operator.
3. In my `main` function, it says there is no matching function call for `Username::NewMember(std::string, std::string)`. hy does it not recognize newMember in main?

   ```
      #include<iostream>
      #include<string>
      using namespace std;

      class Username {
         public:



    string newMember(string existingNames, string newName){

    bool found = false;
    bool match = false;
    string otherName = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(existingNames);i++){
        if(strcmp(existingNames[i], newName) == 0){
            found = true;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(found){
        for(int x = 1;  ; x++){
            match = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(existingNames);i++){
                 if(strcmp(existingNames[i],(newName + x)) == 0){
                    match = true;
                        break;
                }

            }
            if(!match){
                otherName = newName + x;
                break;
            }

        }

        return otherName;

    }





    else return newName;




    }

    int main(){


    string *userNames = new string[4];
    userNames[0] = "Justin";
    userNames[1] = "Justin1";
    userNames[2] = "Justin2";
    userNames[3] = "Justin3";

    cout << newMember(userNames, "Justin") << endl;

    delete[] userNames;

    return 0;


        }
     }
   ```

Comment: Read what `sizeof` does. And there's no reason to use a pointer in `main`.

Comment: While you're at it, read what [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) can do *for you* (answers your "how to compare strings" question in the process), and give your runtime-memory-manager a break by learning the joys of a const-reference parameter when you don't need to *modify* the content or make temp copies.

Comment: There are enough things wrong in java-translated-to-C++ that you need to understand just how different they really are. [See it live here](http://ideone.com/sqZyiA).

Comment: Wow thanks for the example. It will definitly help me. I am trying to solve this problem exactly:[basic links] (http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=2913&rd=5849 ) I must use a class and have a method that only excepts an array of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code :

- If you want to compare two [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)s, simply use the [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) : `string == string2`.
- If you want to append an `int` to a `string` in C++ you can use `streams`:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Justin" << 4;
std::cout << oss.str();
```

- You are passing a `string*` to the function `newMember` but your prototype doesn't match that:

```cpp
string *userNames = new string[4];
newMember(userNames, "Justin"); // Call

string newMember(string existingNames, string newName); // Protype
```

I think it should be: `string newMember(string* existingNames, string newName);`, no?

- In the example, your `main` function is inside your `Username` class. It is not correct in C/C++. Unlike Java, the `main` function has to be in the global scope.
- Finally, you should use [*const-reference parameter*](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) because you don't need to modify the content of them, and you need to copy them anyway:

```cpp
string newMember(string* existingNames, const string& newName);
//                                      ^^^^^       ^
```

Are you sure you need something allocated dynamically in the main function?

Comment: I am getting the error:Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
But I have my main function in my program. why is it not detecting my main function?

Comment: @user2510809 In the example you gave us, it seems that your `main` function is inside the class `Username` but unlike `java`, the `main` function has to be in the global scope.

Comment: @user2510809 I updated my answer to add this to the explanation. Is it working now ?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to access newMember from main. It keeps saying: newMember was not declared in this scope. How do I make newMember global?

Comment: @user2510809 In fact, in your code, the class `Username` is useless. You are not using a `Username` instance here. You should take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789659/what-is-the-best-approach-for-a-java-developer-to-learn-c

Comment: yes but if i make an instance of my class then it should work right?

Comment: In your main you can do : `Username u; u.newMember( ... );` It will work because your `newMember` method is public.